# Adding a Session Value in a Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add value to the Session object in a Controller like this:

```
Request.HttpContext.Session.SetString("key, "value")
```

But I get the next error: The session cannot be established after the response has started.

How can I add a value to the Session object from a controller?

Thank you.

Edit:

This is the code:

```
public IActionResult SetValue()
{
     Request.HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", "aam3");
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where the above line is being used?

Comment: A added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the problem, I had a custom middleware before the `App.UseMvc` statement, in that middleware I had the line `await Context.Response.WriteAsync("Testing Middleware")`, that line inmedaitly started the response, for that reason I wasn't able to change the Session later in the controller.

Thank you.

Comment: so I am assuming you called the `WriteAsync` in the custom middleware `before` you called `await next()` (basically invoking the next middleware, which is MVC in this case)?

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It is working for me and I am using CTP 6.

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Context.Session.SetString("key", "value");
            return View();
        }
```

Also to be more sure it is important that what you have done in Startup.cs file.